# Calling url when apache service starts

Tags: apache2

Is it possible to call a url when the apache service starts?

Comment: On what platform? With which version of Apache?

Comment: apache2, possibly both windows and linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add a line to your `apachectl` script to call a URL via [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) or similar ?

I presume you're doing this to test startup behaviour ? You can check the error code from `wget` (or whichever tool you use) and then take appropriate action.

Comment: not a bad idea.. any way of doing something similar under windows ?